# Batch scripting for loop with setting variables of particular string of the file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having a struggle with loop using "for" and to set the variable for later action.

So briefly explaining about a situation I am facing, 
I have files named "HI_001_1813414.nii.gz" & "HI_001_1813414_T1.nii.gz" , and I want to set each two files' name as a variable, so that I can use it for later action.

Here is my batch script.

```
path=C:\Users\user\Desktop\dsi_studio_64
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir *_T1.nii.gz /b /d') do (

set fname=%%x 

set name=%fname: ~-7%

set dwi_fname = %fname:_T1 =% 

call dsi_studio.exe --action=reg --from=%%x --to=%dwi_fname% --output=%%x_norm.nii.gz --reg_type=0 > "%%x.log.txt"
 )
```

The main problem here is: the variable I set shows only the last one (I checked it with echo).

Comment: Also, `path` is already a system variable. Please don't change its value.

Comment: Remove spaces around `=` in `set` statements as they otherwise become part of the variable name and the assigned value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set values in for loops unless you run this command first:
`SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion`
Also you will need to refer to %var% as !var! while inside the loop.

Comment: This is incorrect. Call set and %%exspansion%% also achieves variable Modification.

Comment: Well, you don't need delayed expansion or `call` to set a variable, you just need one of them to *expand* (read) it...

Comment: Thank you! SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion helps me to get into the loop and set the variables well :)